# Python (Flask) writing unwanted characters at the end of file

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a Flask function that reads a `config.json` file which looks like this:

(Sorry for a longer post but I think I have explained every step nicely)

```
{
    "tip": {
        "models": [
            "Gzip81", 
            "Gzip91"
        ]
    }, 
    "file_upload_dir": "input", 
    "sip": {
        "models": [
            "AnZip12", 
            "AnZip22"
        ]
    }, 
    "lip": {
        "models": [
            "iZip-20", 
            "iZip-160"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have an `update()` function that opens the file and writes new data to the file like this:

```
with open('config.json', 'r+') as f:
        new_data = {
            "file_upload_dir": new_settings['upload_directory'],
            "tip": {"models": new_settings['tip_models']},
            "sip": {"models": new_settings['sip_models']},
            "lip": {"models": new_settings['lip_models']}
        }
        f.seek(0)  # <--- should reset file position to the beginning.
        json.dump(new_data, f, indent=4)
```

When I add more data to keys in the JSON it works just fine and writes correctly into the file like this:

```
{
        "tip": {
            "models": [
                "Gzip81", 
                "Gzip91",
                "StackOverflow" # <- new value
            ]
        }, 
        "file_upload_dir": "input", 
        "sip": {
            "models": [
                "AnZip12", 
                "AnZip22",
                "StackOverflow" # <- new value
            ]
        }, 
        "lip": {
            "models": [
                "iZip-20", 
                "iZip-160",
                "StackOverflow" # <- new value
            ]
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to delete the same `"StackOverflow"` entry from the keys the file is written with some weird data at the end of the file by making the JSON file invalid like this:

```
    {
            "tip": {
                "models": [
                    "Gzip81", 
                    "Gzip91"

                ]
            }, 
            "file_upload_dir": "input", 
            "sip": {
                "models": [
                    "AnZip12", 
                    "AnZip22"
                ]
            }, 
            "lip": {
                "models": [
                    "iZip-20", 
                    "iZip-160"
                ]
            }
        }ackOverflow" # <-- where does this come from???
        ]
    }
}
```

The Flask error I get is:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 30 column 13 - line 34 column 2 (char 529 - 576)
```

Comment: Use access mode `w` instead of `r+` to open the file.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. It looks like that fixed it :)